# SPWebCollection.WebsInfo.Description - always null

Tags: 2010, development

I am trying to get `Description` value from each `SPWeb`'s `SPWebInfo` object:

```
DataTable _websinfo = new DataTable("WebsInfo");
_websinfo.Columns.Add("Title");
_websinfo.Columns.Add("Url");
_websinfo.Columns.Add("Description");

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        foreach (SPWebInfo webInfo in web.Webs.WebsInfo)
        {
            _websinfo.Rows.Add(webInfo.Title, webInfo.ServerRelativeUrl, webInfo.Description);
        }
    }
}
```

I can get correct `Title` and `ServerRelativeUrl` with no problem but the `Description` is always null!

I've checked the webs with SharePoint Manager 2010 and they definitely have the `Description` value set.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a SharePoint bug?

Answer (score 1):

I also checked, the description comes as null. I second your thought. This may be a bug. You can however use following variant of code to get the description of subwebs:

```
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{                   
    foreach (SPWeb subWeb in web.Webs)
    {
        using (subWeb)
        {
            string desc = subWeb.Description;
            string url = subWeb.ServerRelativeUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but according to this page: http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2011/07/perfect-loop-looping-through-all-webs.html and this page: http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Vardhaman/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=24 this way would be much slower, especially for many SPWebs - and it makes me sad.